# Spring Bean injection fails on OpenShift

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, dependency-injection, openshift

I added a new Spring Integration configuration with Spring Messaging into our Spring Boot application.
The application deploys and runs properly on my MAC.

However,
when deployed to OpenShift (using OpenJDK) or Docker runtime
deployments fail with the following error:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel' available:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
Dependency annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=ftpChannel)}
```

Here is a simplified version of the code failing with the same error:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class FtpService {

    private final MessageChannel ftpClientInboundChannel;

    public FtpService(@Qualifier("ftpChannel") MessageChannel ftpClientInboundChannel) {
        this.ftpClientInboundChannel = ftpClientInboundChannel;
    }
}

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.IntegrationComponentScan;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException;


@Configuration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class FtpClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannel")
    public MessageHandler ftpPayableHandler() {

        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {

            }
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by adding of a message channel bean:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel ftpChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```